# 2D Array elements do not save values in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    double** F = (double**) malloc(4097 * sizeof(double*));;
    int flops = 0;
    int i, j, k;
    double r;

    for (i=0; i<4097; i++) {
        F[i] = (double*) malloc(4097*sizeof(double));
    }

    // insert code to initialize array elements to random values between 1.0 and 2.0
    for (i=0; i<4097; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<4097; j++) {
            r = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX/2.0);
            F[i][j] = r;
            printf("%f %f\n", r, F[i,j]);
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to generate random numbers and store them into a 4097 x 4097 array but when the above code is run the array is not updated.

Comment: `F[i][j]` is not the same as `F[i,j]`

Comment: @xsun That's because you corrected the wrong line :)

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
        printf("%f %f\n", r, F[i,j]);
```

should be

```
        printf("%f %f\n", r, F[i][j]);
```

However, the reason it's a valid syntax is because of the *comma operator*. Comma operator evaluates its operands and yields only the last operand's value. So,

```
        printf("%f %f\n", r, F[i,j]);
```

is equivalent to

```
        printf("%f %f\n", r, F[j]);
```

However, this has a problem. `F[j]` is of type `double *` whereas `%f` expects a `double`. GCC warns:

```
    warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3  
has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
```

Increasing your compiler warning levels would help catch these.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the comma operator `F[i,j]`? The array populates correctly... just replace this with `F[i][j]` to verify.

Also, free your memory.